# Applying css to odd/even rows created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several tables that are created dynamically.  Rows can be up to 1000+.  After creating the rows, I run the below code:

```
$('[id$=TestGrid]').not('tr:first').each(function () {
    $('tr:odd', this).addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
    $('tr:even', this).addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
});
```

or should I be doing

```
$('[id$=TestGrid]').not('tr:first').each(function () {
    $('tr:nth-child(odd)', this).addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
    $('tr:nth-child(even)', this).addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
});
```

Since, it is dynamic, I don't know the ID's but I do know they will end with "...TestGrid".

Will any of the above cause reflow problems? and if so, how can I fix this??

Thanks!

Comment: What you really should be doing to paint odd/even rows is to use CSS.

Comment: What is `[id$=TestGrid]`? A table or table row?

Comment: why do you don´t add to your tr´s the odd and even class during the creation/generation? This would be 1000 times faster than run jquery through it and it´s also totally uneccessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the CSS [**`:nth-child` pseudo class**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) to style the rows:

```css
/* odd rows plus skip first row */
tr[id$=TestGrid]:nth-child(2n + 3) { ... }

/* even rows */
tr[id$=TestGrid]:nth-child(2n) { ... }
```

You can also use the above selectors as-is in jQuery code:

```
$('tr[id$=TestGrid]:nth-child(2n + 3)').addClass("odd").removeClass("even");
$('tr[id$=TestGrid]:nth-child(2n)').addClass("even").removeClass("odd");
```

The nth-child pseudo class is [explained here](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/03/css-nth-child-selector-pwned.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'd wanna use css like so:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #f1f1f1; }
```

and/or

```
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #fff; }
```